# How to pass through dropdown selection using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a dropdown on a landing page that needs to pass through the value to a data extension once the drop down selection has been chosen and the page has been submitted. I can request the parameter on the landing page, but I am unsure of how I'd set that parameter for the drop down.

```
       <fieldset id="reason">
        <p>Please let us know.....</p>
            <select name="reason" class="required">
                <option value="" selected>Select...</option>
                <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
                <option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>

                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>               
        </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I've done in the past is something like this:

```
%%[
var @title
set @title = AttributeValue("formalTitle")
]%%
<select name="Title" id="title">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Title</option>
    <option value="DR" %%=iif(@Title == "DR","selected='selected'","")=%%>Dr.</option>
    <option value="MR" %%=iif(@Title == "MR","selected='selected'","")=%%>Mr.</option>
    <option value="MRS" %%=iif(@Title == "MRS","selected='selected'","")=%%>Mrs.</option>
    <option value="MS" %%=iif(@Title == "MS","selected='selected'","")=%%>Ms.</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does the @Title variable need to be set outside of the drop down?

Comment: Yes.  I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: When I set the @title it only passes through that value. The selected value is not being updated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: If we set the @title = "Dr" and then select "Mr." from the dropdown, once our page executes and passes through the value, it will only pass through the value that is initially set. The drop down selection is not updating.

Comment: What we are trying to do is pass through the value of the value selected via the drop down.

Comment: AMPScript is server-side -- meaning it'll be evaluated at page load (for defaulting the value in this case).  The current value of the select statement is client-side.  You'll need to retrieve the current value of the select from the POST on the resulting page.

Comment: So we cannot use any validation script to determine the value and pass it through via an upsert? Thanks for all your help btw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18892/discussion-between-adam-spriggs-and-realrx7).

Comment: It won't allow me to talk on chat

Comment: Yes, you can, but the Upsert will need to be server-side. Perhaps this will help: pastebin.com/6sai85pY. This is a shell of a custom preference center that posts to itself, but it shows the defaulting of values with on page load and then retrieving the form values when the form is posted.